# Python Iterative Loop Plot values

Tags: python, for-loop, pde, iteration

I am trying to carry out an iterative calculation in python using a finite difference method.  I found the finite difference method from this:

http://depa.fquim.unam.mx/amyd/archivero/DiferenciasFinitas3_25332.pdf

The values that the code calculates are correct.  The problem is that it is only showing the final values.  What I want is to extract the values for any point in the x-direction so that I can plot them, as well as extract the values at any point in time e.g the values of the points halfway through the calculations.  Is this the right way for doing an iterative calculation? The code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import time
import matplotlib as p
L=0.005
Nx=3
T=5
N1=5
k=0.5
rho=1200
c=1000
a=(k/(rho*c))
x = np.linspace(0, L, Nx+1)   # mesh points in space
dx = x[1] - x[0]
t = np.linspace(0, T, N1)    # time
dt = t[1] - t[0]
toutside=5
Coefficient = a*dt/dx**2
bi=0.5
ui = sp.zeros(Nx+1)
u = sp.zeros(Nx+1)
for i in range(Nx+1):
  ui[i] = 50 # initial values

for n in range(0, N1):

   for i in range(0,1):
      u[i] = 2*Coefficient*(ui[i+1]+bi*toutside)+(1-2*Coefficient-2*bi*Coefficient)*ui[i]
   for i in range(1,Nx):
      u[i] = Coefficient*(ui[i+1]+ui[i-1])+(1-2*Coefficient)*ui[i]
   for i in range(Nx,Nx+1):
      u[i] = 2*Coefficient*(ui[i-1])+(1-2*Coefficient)*ui[i]
      ui[:]= u #updates matrix for next loop
 print ui
```

I've modified my code to based on danodonovan answer to:

```
for n in range(0, N1):

for i in range(0,1):
    u[i] = 2*Coefficient*(ui[i+1]+bi*toutside)+(1-2*Coefficient-2*bi*Coefficient)*ui[i]
for i in range(1,Nx):
    u[i] = Coefficient*(ui[i+1]+ui[i-1])+(1-2*Coefficient)*ui[i]
for i in range(Nx,Nx+1):
    u[i] = 2*Coefficient*(ui[i-1])+(1-2*Coefficient)*ui[i]
    ui=u
    a=list(ui)

print a
```

When I try to take the entire list out of the loop, only the final values are produced. How do I extract the whole list?  Is this the right way to do an iterative calculation using the values of the previous row to calculate the values of the new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a starter indent the `print ui` to see the values of `ui` for all `N1`. Then append your results to a list:

```
res = []
for n in range(0, N1):

   for i in range(0,1):
      u[i] = 2*Coefficient*(ui[i+1]+bi*toutside)+(1-2*Coefficient-2*bi*Coefficient)*ui[i]
   for i in range(1,Nx):
      u[i] = Coefficient*(ui[i+1]+ui[i-1])+(1-2*Coefficient)*ui[i]
   for i in range(Nx,Nx+1):
      u[i] = 2*Coefficient*(ui[i-1])+(1-2*Coefficient)*ui[i]
      ui[:]= u #updates matrix for next loop
   print ui
   res.append(ui.copy())

print res
```

Produces this result:

```
[array([ 41.5625,  50.    ,  50.    ,  50.    ]),
 array([ 37.87109375,  48.41796875,  50.        ,  50.        ]),
 array([ 35.6628418 ,  46.73706055,  49.70336914,  50.        ]),
 array([ 34.06639099,  45.21682739,  49.20280457,  49.88876343]),
 array([ 32.79785633,  43.87349129,  48.58405113,  49.63152885])]
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion but it only produced the last row of the iteration.

Comment: Of course, you over write the array at each time step. Adding a `.copy()` does the trick. Hint: You should really have look at a NumPy tutorial and learn how to work with whole array operations. Your code can be much improved.

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand your question correctly) Using `matplotlib` you can do

```
 import matplotlib as p

 # and after your loop has completed

 p.pyplot.plot(range(0, N1), ui, 'o-')
 p.pyplot.show()
```

to get a simple plot of your data `u` against `range(0, N1)`.

I don't know what you expect `ui` to be `ui[:]= u` is an odd thing to be doing - it sets a copy of `ui`  to `u` but you don't retain the copy of `ui` that `ui[:]` is producing.

*Hint: think about `ui[:]` as being the same as `list(ui)`*

Comment: I'm not sure that's what you want either, every time you iterate through your last loop, you're re-writing `a`